# Yet another "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket" after a security update

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-10.04, socket

**SOLVED**

As yoonix pointed out, it was only an issue with the root partition being full...
Thanks for your help!

-

So yes, this question has been asked several times, here and elsewhere.
I apologize in advance if this one doesn't deserve a new thread.

Exact error message is:

`Link to database cannot be established: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Here's the background.
One of my clients hosts his site on a dedicated server running Ubuntu 10.04.
Today, he told me he had issues with his mailserver as he wasn't able to receive anything.
I tried sending him one, never to be received, tried my own account on this server, same thing.
Nothing seemed wrong at the datacenter and the mails weren't bounced back so I checked the log and saw this:

`warning: not enough free space in mail queue: 7573504 bytes < 1.5*message size limit`

So I told him it was OK, that's something that happens once or twice a year on this setup (lack of space).
FYI, I'm not the one who setup the server. I know enough to do some basic maintenance, but I'm no linux-guru sadly.
So I did some cleaning and took the opportunity to install the *security* updates that were pending.
Everything went well (at least no errors showed up during the process) and I then proceeded to restart the server.

After a quite fast (faster than usual it seems) reboot, I got this lovely error message instead of the site.
Spent couple hours researching and testing some of the solutions that seemed relevant, but so far, no luck.
Most of them involve reinstalling (or even installing) mysql.
In this case, here are the packages installed on the server:

```
mysql-client-5.1        5.1.73-0ubuntu0.10.04.1
mysql-client-core-5.1   5.1.73-0ubuntu0.10.04.1
mysql-common            5.1.73-0ubuntu0.10.04.1
mysql-server            5.1.73-0ubuntu0.10.04.1
mysql-server-5.1        5.1.73-0ubuntu0.10.04.1
mysql-server-core-5.1   5.1.73-0ubuntu0.10.04.1
```

So I think it's safe to assume I'm not missing any mysql components.
If I try to start the service (because it simply doesn't start at all), I just end up with a "job failed" message.
I looked at the mysql error log and nothing shows up, apart from this error:

`[ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_c46_0.MYI'; try to repair it`

This one appears few times and the timestamps seem to indicate it only occurred during the update process.
And as far as I know, it's probably unrelated and not worrisome.
In any case, the DBs are backed up each night.

One thing I have yet to try is to reinstall mysql.
Mostly because I fear it may break up something else.
And I'm not exactly sure if the space issue is cleared, don't know what else to clear after doing an *apt-get autoremove*.
Here's what *df -h* says:

```
rootfs                 10G  9,5G     0 100% /
/dev/root              10G  9,5G     0 100% /
/dev                  4,0G  164K  4,0G   1% /dev
none                  4,0G     0  4,0G   0% /dev/shm
none                  4,0G  1,1M  4,0G   1% /var/run
none                  4,0G     0  4,0G   0% /var/lock
none                  4,0G     0  4,0G   0% /lib/init/rw
/dev/md2              914G  115G  754G  14% /home
```

There's only 1.1M free on /var/run/, but I don't think that socket file needs that much.
If anyone has some advices on what I should do next, it'll be nice!

Here the content of *my.cnf*:

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
user            = mysql
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /home/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
skip-external-locking
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
log_error                = /var/log/mysql/error.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 16M

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Comment: `I got this lovely error message instead of the site`  <-- What error?  `There's only 1.1M free on /var/run/, but I don't think that socket file needs that much.`  You are reading the df output wrong.  1.1M USED, 4.0GB free.  The root filesystem is full (for everyone other than root from the looks of it).  That percentage on the end tells you how much is used, not how much is free.  That needs to be corrected.  As for the mysql error about the table, that looks like it's a temp table.  It can probably be removed (although I'd move it to another directory myself).

Comment: The one that says it can't connect to local mysql due to that missing socket file.
As for the disk usage, yeah sorry, I read that wrong...

Comment: Right, and the socket is missing because the server isn't running.

Comment: Yeah I figured that, but it refuses to start.
It should auto-start to begin with, but it doesn't.
Launching it manually end with a "job failed".

Comment: .. because of the '/tmp/#sql_c46_0.MYI' file being invalid.  What likely happened was MySQL was working on a temporary table or rebuilding an existing table and the disk got full, preventing it from completing the write.  Move that file out of /tmp/ and try to start it up again, after you have freed up space.

Comment: The "tmp" folder is empty (autoremove, restarts...).
So most likely, all those issues come from that "root" partition that needs to get more space? I hope :) Thanks for your inputs!